# How to iterate columns in datatable using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I did for loop inside the columns, but it gives me an error. I would, therefore, like to know how to iterate over the columns inside the columns in datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": "data/objects_deep.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "hr.position" },
            { "data": "contact.0" },
            { "data": "contact.1" },
            { "data": "hr.start_date" },
            { "data": "hr.salary" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery $.each()

Comment: for(var j = 0 ; j <9 ;j++){   { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "hr.position" },
        { "data": "contact.0" },
        { "data": "contact.1" },
        { "data": "hr.start_date" },
        { "data": "hr.salary" }  }? possible